# How to insert JComboBox editable and dynamic in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a `JTable` with `JComboBox` and it is ok. Now I want to set this ComboBox editable, and I want also that the user can add the element from this ComboBox  automatically into my database.

So the user can select one of all the components on this `comboBox` or the user can add a new element. The problem is that the `JComboBox` is a column of my table. So I have this but it does not work:

```
public void setUpColumnTaglia(JTable table, TableColumn taglia) {
    String[] listaDescrizione = new String[0];
    if(listaTaglie!=null){
        listaDescrizione = new String[listaTaglie.size()];
        int i=0;
        for (Taglia t : listaTaglie) {
            listaDescrizione[i++]= t.getDescrizione();
        }
    }

    textcomboBoxTaglia = new AutoComplete(listaDescrizione);        
    editorBoxTaglia = (JTextComponent)textcomboBoxTaglia.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
    editorBoxTaglia.setText("");

    taglia.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(textcomboBoxTaglia));
    //Set up tool tips for the sport cells.
    DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer =
        new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    renderer.setToolTipText("Seleziona Taglia");
    taglia.setCellRenderer(renderer);
}
```

class AutoComplete:

```
package com.mcsolution.common.Componenti_Swing;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AutoComplete extends JComboBox implements JComboBox.KeySelectionManager
{
    private String searchFor;
    private long lap;
    public class CBDocument extends PlainDocument
    {
        public void insertString(int offset, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException
        {
            if (str==null) return;
            super.insertString(offset, str, a);
            if(!isPopupVisible() && str.length() != 0) fireActionEvent();
        }
    }
    public AutoComplete(Object[] items)
    {
        super(items);
        lap = new java.util.Date().getTime();
        setKeySelectionManager(this);
        JTextField tf;
        if(getEditor() != null)
        {
            tf = (JTextField)getEditor().getEditorComponent();
            if(tf != null)
            {
                tf.setDocument(new CBDocument());
                addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
                    {
                        try{
                            JTextField tf = (JTextField)getEditor().getEditorComponent();
                            String text = tf.getText();
                            ComboBoxModel aModel = getModel();
                            String current;
                            for(int i = 0; i < aModel.getSize(); i++)
                            {
                                current = aModel.getElementAt(i).toString();
                                if(current.toLowerCase().startsWith(text.toLowerCase()))
                                {
                                    tf.setText(current);
                                    tf.setSelectionStart(text.length());
                                    tf.setSelectionEnd(current.length());
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e){

                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    public void fireActionEvent()
    {
        super.fireActionEvent();
    }

}
```

For me the problem is on this line code:

```
taglia.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(textcomboBoxTaglia));
```

because I should put `editorComboBoxTaglia` but if I try to do it, I have an error:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: What's `ComboFormat`? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Could you give the details of the error you are having?

Comment: Do you want to set the whole `JComboBox` as the editor or just the textComponent of the `JComboBox` as editor?

Comment: Your code show `taglia.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(textcomboBoxTaglia));` where as the image shows `taglia.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(editorBoxTaglia));` could you clarify that point?

Comment: In my code there is textComboBoxTaglia but I have write that for fixed my problem I should insert in setCellEditor editorBoxTaglia, but if I try to do it, I have an error and I have insert this error in the picture

Comment: So what you mean to say is that you **do not want** to set the `JComboBox` to the CellEditor but **you want to** set the editor of the `JComboBox`. If I am correct could you tell me why?

Comment: Yes I want set an editor because I want to add items dynamically at this combo box and insert this new items in database

Comment: Then why use the editor of the `JComboBox`? Simply use `JTextField`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78157/discussion-between-bircastri-and-blip).